# Inconsistent Quick Sort Function

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

So I have written this quick sort function, and it works for SOME input.
For example it works for the following inputs : "*5 4 3 2 1*", "*3 4 5 6 7*", etc.
However when I input something like : "*0 3 5 4 -5 100 7777 2014*" it will always mix up the multi digit numbers.
 
I was hoping someone could help point me to where my code is failing at this test case.

**Sort.cpp**

```
std::vector<int> QuickSort::sortFunc(std::vector<int> vec, int left, int right) {
int i = left, j = right;
int tmp;
int pivot = vec.at( (left + right) / 2 );

/* partition */
while (i <= j) { 
    while (vec.at(i) < pivot)
        i++;
    while (vec.at(j) > pivot)
        j--;
    if (i <= j) {
        tmp = vec.at(i);
        vec.at(i) = vec.at(j);
        vec.at(j) = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

/* recursion */
if (left < j)
    return sortFunc( vec, left, j );
if (i < right)
    return sortFunc( vec, i, right );
else
{
    return vec;
}
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
 int main()
{

// The user inputs a string of numbers (e.g. "6 4 -2 88 ..etc") and those integers are then put into a vector named 'vec'.
std::vector<int> vec;

// Converts string from input into integer values, and then pushes said values into vector.
std::string line;
if ( getline(std::cin, line) )
{
    std::istringstream str(line);

    int value;
    str >> value;
    vec.push_back( value );
    while ( str >> value ) 
    {
        vec.push_back( value );
    }
}
// Creating QuickSort object.
QuickSort qSort;
QuickSort *ptrQSort = &qSort;
// Creating new vector that has been 'Quick Sorted'.
int vecSize = vec.size();
std::vector<int> qSortedVec;
qSortedVec = ptrQSort->sortFunc( vec, 0, vecSize-1 );

// Middle, start, and end positions on the vector.
int mid = ( 0 + (vec.size()-1) )  / 2;
int start = 0, end = vec.size() - 1;

// Creating RecursiveBinarySearch object.
RecursiveBinarySearch bSearch;
RecursiveBinarySearch *ptrBSearch = &bSearch;
//bool bS = ptrBSearch->binarySearch( qSortedVec, mid, start, end );
bool bS = ptrBSearch->binarySearch( bSortedVec, mid, start, end );


/*--------------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Print out inputted integers and the binary search result.

// Depending on the binary search, print either 'true' or 'false'.
if ( bS == 1 )
{
    std::cout << "true ";
}
if ( bS == 0 )
{
    std::cout << "false ";
}

// Prints the result of the 'quick sorted' array.
int sortedSize = qSortedVec.size();
for ( int i = 0; i < sortedSize; i++ )
{
    std::cout << qSortedVec[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";


return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any and all help you can give me guys.

Comment: Does it go wrong during the actual sorting routine, or earlier, during the reading from stdin?

Comment: It appears to go wrong during the sorting. As I have created a bubble sort function that is able to read in and sort the same integers correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves it completely, but after sorting the left part, you still need to sort the right part, but you already return instead.

Also, passing the vector by value and returning it is overhead and not needed, because in the end there should only be one version of the vector, so passing by reference is preferred.  Passing by value and returning is sometimes needed when doing recursion, especially when backtracking (looking for different paths), but not in this case where left and right provide the needed state.